# Node.next.next in Java Explanation

Tags: java, linked-list

Can someone explain to me this

```
 node.val=node.next.val;
 node.next=node.next.next;
```

Will the second line of code here push the succeeding elements
for example

the link list is [4,5,1,9]
and the node to be remeved is 4

My understanding is that the value of the first node will be 5
and the value of the second node will be 1

to my understanding the new linked list will be [5,1,1,9]

how does the succeding node be pushed after the firs element

thanks in advance for those who will answer i really find linked list hard

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to provide a [mre]? Also, if you know how to use a debugger, it may help to step through the code to see what is going on.

Comment: If you have [4, 5, 1, 9] and removed the 4, why would you think the result will be [5, 1, 1, 9]? The result will be [5, 1, 9].

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps to visiualise it.

Let's depict your example list, and the `node` variable that has a reference to its first node:

```
  node
   ↓
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 4  │   │ data: 5  │   │ data: 1  │   │ data: 9  │
│ next: ──────►│ next: ──────►│ next: ──────►│ next:null│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

Now the first of the two statements is executed:

```
node.val=node.next.val;
```

This means that `node.val` will be assigned 5:

```
  node
   ↓
┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 5  │   │ data: 5  │   │ data: 1  │   │ data: 9  │
│ next: ──────►│ next: ──────►│ next: ──────►│ next:null│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

So far, so good. Now the tricky one. This statement assigns a *reference*:

```
node.next=node.next.next;
```

First realise what `node.next.next` is. It is a reference to the node with value 1. Just follow the links in the above image, from `node` via its `next` member to the second node, and there via its `next` member we see the third node.

That reference is assigned to `node.next`. This has the following effect:

```
  node
   ↓         ┌─────────────┐
┌──────────┐ │ ┌──────────┐│  ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 5  │ │ │ data: 5  │└─►│ data: 1  │   │ data: 9  │
│ next: ─────┘ │ next: ──────►│ next: ──────►│ next:null│
└──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

Now we get in a situation where the second node no longer is part of the chain that starts with the `node` reference. Actually, there is nothing anymore that references that second node, and there is no code that has the possibility to find it somehow.
This means it is as if that node is not there at all. And so the above picture is no different from:

```
  node
   ↓
┌──────────┐                  ┌──────────┐   ┌──────────┐
│ data: 5  │                  │ data: 1  │   │ data: 9  │
│ next: ─────────────────────►│ next: ──────►│ next:null│
└──────────┘                  └──────────┘   └──────────┘
```

I hope this clarifies it.